# Insert Checkbox Selected Value into Database

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to insert selected checkbox values to database. But I get an error

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List` to type 'System.String'

Please help. Thanks.

Model:

```
public class CheckboxModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Checked { get; set; }
}

public class MainModel
{
    public List<CheckboxModel> CheckBoxes { get; set; }
}
```

HomeController:

```
// Get
public ActionResult Index()
{
    MainModel model = new MainModel();
    var list = new List<CheckboxModel>
    {
         new CheckboxModel{Id = 1, Name = "Male", Checked = false},
         new CheckboxModel{Id = 2, Name = "Female", Checked = false},
    };
    model.CheckBoxes = list;
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Checkboxes")] MainModel model)
{
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.MainModel.Add(model);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(MainModel);
}
```

View:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
      @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Checkboxes.Count; i++)
                {
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Checkboxes[i].Id)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Checkboxes[i].Name)
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model.Checkboxes[i].Checked)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.Checkboxes[i].Name)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

                }
```

Comment: Can you add the right tags to your question so that the right people can find it? I don't see any react code here

Comment: oops. Fixed tag.

Comment: Is it an example or are you creating checkbox for gender? I believe radio control would be the right choice here as no one will select more than one gender at a time.

Comment: I used a bad example here. I am creating a checkbox to let user select type of manikins, male, female, newborn, etc.